# SQLITE Date Comparison with different years

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date

When I execute the following query: `SELECT startDate, endDate FROM HasBeenReserved NATURAL JOIN House NATURAL JOIN Reservation WHERE houseID=1 AND startDate < '4/12/2020';`

I get the following results:

```
startDate|endDate
09/12/2019|09/12/2019
11/12/2019|11/12/2019
```

No problem so far.

But when I try this one: `SELECT startDate, endDate FROM HasBeenReserved NATURAL JOIN House NATURAL JOIN Reservation WHERE houseID=1 AND startDate < '1/12/2020';` where I just changed 4/12/2020 for 1/12/20, which should return the same results, I get the following:

```
startDate|endDate
09/12/2019|09/12/2019
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: The format of the dates is: `dd/MM/yyyy` which is not comparable because dates in SQLite are strings and are compared as strings. Change the format to: `yyyy/MM/dd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a proper date format.

SQLite wants dates in format `yyy-mm-dd`. What is happening with your code is that SQLite is doing string comparison. String-wise, `'11/12/2019'` is smaller than `'4/12/2020'` (because the former starts with `'1'` and the latter with `'4'`), but greater than `'1/12/2020'` (because `'1/'` is greater than `'11'`).

I would urge you to convert your data to proper date formats. For this, you can do string manipulations:

```
update mytable set
    startDate = 
        substr(startDate, 7) 
        || '-' || substr(startDate, 4, 2) 
        || '-' || substr(startDate, 1, 2),
    endDate = 
        substr(endDate , 7) 
        || '-' || substr(endDate , 4, 2) 
        || '-' || substr(endDate , 1, 2)
;
```

Afterwards, you can do proper date comparisons, like:

```
startDate < '2020-12-01' -- or '2020-12-04'
```